# Minimal addChild(var) for a dojo TabContainer

Tags: javascript, extjs, dojo

I'm currently converting some of my dojo to ExtJS, but I can't convert everything at once. I have a set of tabs in dojo that need to stay in Dojo, however the container they show once I click on them need to display a div that I can use as a renderTo for my Ext code.

I need the minimal code for a dojoTabContainer, so I can use renderTo and put my ext component in there.

Apologies if this was a messy post.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be tricky because the child of the TabContainer must inherits from `dijit._widgetBase`.

I think you'd better create a wrapper : create a Dojo widget which is a TabContainer and which contains your ExtJs component.
That way you can control the life cycle as you need.